# Logoff Disconnected Users

Tags: windows-7

I'm using this batch :

```
query user > logoff.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in (logoff.txt) DO if /I [%%i]==[%1] logoff.exe %%j
del logoff
```

It works with one user only , but if i want to logoff many users in the same time , what can I do any help?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the FOR loop.

If you are going to logoff multiple people then you are going to have to provide a list of names to be logged off. Your first line creates that list and puts it into the file(logoff.txt). The second line compares this list of names to a name you provide when you call the script(%1), when it gets a match it logs that person off. So change it to logoff all names in the list. But you will still need to decide how you will provide that list when you call the script.

Comment: I guess char didn't answer back. Well done. Thanks, it helped me. Maybe char got burned?